# RM disappears whenever MapReduce example is ran

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have 3 VMs, 1Master, 2Slaves
Whenever i run both commands in my Master VM: `start-dfs.sh` and `start-yarn.sh`, the logs show me totally clean, no errors! With `jps` showing all cool. But whenever I start a `hadoop jar ./share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar pi 2 5` and when i do `jps`, my ResourceManager disappears. And when I restart yarn. this message appears:

```
slave1: nodemanager running as process 6011. Stop it first.
```

and after the example MR ran, the console gave me:

```
INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: ubuntu-378e53c1-3e1f-4f6e-904d-00ef078fe3f8/50.50.1.9:8040. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
```

Any suggestions is welcome, I'm like all day to figuring it out.

From my MASTER VM

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
50.50.1.9 ubuntu-378e53c1-3e1f-4f6e-904d-00ef078fe3f8
50.50.1.8 slave1
50.50.1.4 slave2
```

core-site.xml

```
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://ubuntu-378e53c1-3e1f-4f6e-904d-00ef078fe3f8:9000</value>

<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.2.0/tmp</value>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>3</value>

<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hdfs/namenode</value>

<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hdfs/datanode</value>

<name>dfs.permissions</name>
<value>false</value>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce.shuffle</value>

<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>

<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>ubuntu-378e53c1-3e1f-4f6e-904d-00ef078fe3f8:8025</value>

<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>ubuntu-378e53c1-3e1f-4f6e-904d-00ef078fe3f8:8030</value>

<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>ubuntu-378e53c1-3e1f-4f6e-904d-00ef078fe3f8:8040</value>

<name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
<value>ubuntu-378e53c1-3e1f-4f6e-904d-00ef078fe3f8:8141</value>
```

and my slave is like this:
core-site.xml

```
<name>fs.default.name</name>
<value>hdfs://ubuntu-378e53c1-3e1f-4f6e-904d-00ef078fe3f8:9000</value>
<name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
<value>/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.2.0/tmp</value>
```

core-site.xml

```
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hdfs/namenode</value>

<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/home/ubuntu/hadoop-2.2.0/etc/hdfs/datanode</value>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>

<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>ubuntu-378e53c1-3e1f-4f6e-904d-00ef078fe3f8:8025</value>

<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>ubuntu-378e53c1-3e1f-4f6e-904d-00ef078fe3f8:8030</value>

<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>ubuntu-378e53c1-3e1f-4f6e-904d-00ef078fe3f8:8040</value>

<name>yarn.resourcemanager.admin.address</name>
<value>ubuntu-378e53c1-3e1f-4f6e-904d-00ef078fe3f8:8141</value>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm trying to connect this VM by itself `ubuntu-378e53c1-3e1f-4f6e-904d-00ef078fe3f8/50.50.1.9:8040.`, I forgot to `cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub >> .ssh/authorizedkeys` and It worked.